# zerolog prevents go runtime from "deadlocking" on my machine

Tags: go

I've stumbled upon a very peculiar case. Apparently https://github.com/rs/zerolog prevents my program from "deadlocking".

This is an example of the program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

When I run this on my laptop (go version go1.16.10 linux/amd64) the program just doesn't end. When I try to run it on go playground it does hit deadlock after a few seconds though, I'm not sure why: https://go.dev/play/p/6rkw0jed-6z

My zerolog version is v1.26.0

I suspect some side effect inside zerolog library causes this behavior, but can't figure out which, and can't figure out how to circumvent it... The problem is - it's making my program unsafe to use (I'm writing a piece of code which utilizes channels a lot, and not having this "safe check" is extremely dangerous).

**EDIT**:

As correctly pointed out in the comments, it does seem that zerolog opens another goroutine which is not blocking.

Basically it means that I can not rely on the "checkdead" functionality of the runtime, since I don't know which package might have that side effect (spawning goroutines).

What is the safe and correct way from the receiver's standpoint to end the program if it's impossible that data will be sent into the channel?

I think the obvious answer is timeout but I don't know how much time it can take for the data to appear - but maybe that's the only way?

**EDIT #2**

To clarify my question and motive. So far the comments have all been in a tone that I'm asking something silly (that can not be solved - or even considered to be solved). To clarify: I'm not asking "how not write code that deadlocks". Golang has a built-in "check" that checks if code is stuck: https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.10/src/runtime/proc.go#5038. So clearly there was an attempt to a general purpose solution from the very language developers.

Obviously as practice shows, this check can be "broken". In this case by a package side effect (then again why would zerolog spawn any goroutines during the `init` phase is beyond my understanding). **So I'm asking is there another way to come up with a general solution that could potentially account for those additional factors.**

If you think there can not be such solution, well it may be true, but maybe someone has an idea.

**EDIT #3**

After further comments from @JimB it seems that it is indeed a problem that can not be fix with a general solution, because of no ability to have knowledge of other running goroutines and blocking conditions.

So the strategy to detect "deadlocks" in the program should be unique to every possible "blocking" operation it has.

I'll leave this open just for the informational purpose.

Comment: It's not clear what the expected and actual behaviors are, or why you think it is zerolog's fault. Can you elaborate on your test iterations?

Comment: The `main()` function does deadlock.  The deadlock is not reported because the goroutines started by zerolog are not deadlocked.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart if zerolog is not imported, the program panics with "deadlock" message. That is the expected scenario for the program which has a lock that can not be lifted.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thank you, that makes sense. How can I protect my program while using zerolog? Meaning how can I use channels without worrying that my program will be locked forever if I made a mistake.

Comment: `kill -3` will cause the program to dump information about its goroutines.  I don't know how to take the output, but it doesn't seem to report any extra goroutines.

Comment: @SlayerBirden The problem is not confined to zerolog.  Any goroutine can keep the application "live".  The strategy for detecting a stuck application will depend on the specifics of the application.

Comment: program is waiting for something to read from the channel....

Comment: Asking how to not write code that deadlocks is just like asking how to not write code that crashes —there is no magic bullet, it requires diligence and testing. How long to wait on a channel operation depends on the individual problems being solved.

Comment: @JimB please see my edit#2

Comment: There is no attempt at a general purpose solution for deadlock detection in the runtime; there is a check that can detect the simplest deadlock condition, because that is all that can be detected. There is no general solution, because determining if a program can proceed requires prior knowledge of all the possible blocking conditions. What you’re describing is just another form of the [halting problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: @JimB thanks for clarifying, that makes sense.